# In magento 2 add extension attribute to endpoint /V1/inventory/source-items

Tags: magento2

I would like to add extension_attribute in endpoint `/V1/inventory/source-items`

1. create module
2. add file `extension_attributes.xml`

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\InventoryApi\Api\SourceItemsSaveInterface">
    <attribute
        code="main_warehouse_qty"
        type="int"
    />
</extension_attributes>
```

3. I add Plugin

```
    <type name="Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemInterface">
        <plugin name="mainWarehouseQty"
                type="\Vendor\Backend\Plugin\MainWarehouseQty"
                sortOrder="1"
        />
    </type>
```

Inside

But I do not know what too add here to scalar attribute, and I can't find this interface in code.

I get error:

> does not have accessor method "getMainWarehouseQty" in class "Magento\InventoryApi\Api\Data\SourceItemExtensionInterface".",

Can any one help in this?